# Whether the power series $z^{2^{n}}$ converges at the boundary?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to find the radius of convergence of the series $$\sum z^{2^{n}}$$ and whether it converges at this radius as well.

Attempt: $$\sum z^{2^{n}} = \sum a_kz^k $$, where $$a_k=\begin{cases} 1, k=2^n \text{ with } n \in \mathbb{N}\\0, \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

From this, $\limsup (a_k)^{1/k} = 1$, which implies that $R=1$.

Clearly, if $z=1, z=-1, z=i, z=-i,$ the series diverges because it will just be the series $\sum 1$. But, how do I systematically check all cases with $\lvert z \lvert = 1$?

Comment: Use the [trivial test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $|z|=1$, then $\left|z^{2^n}\right|=1$. So, you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}z^{2^n}=0$, and therefore your series diverges.

Answer (score 4):

What happens to $\|e^{i(2^nt)}\|$ as $n\to\infty$? Does it ever go to $0$?

---

$$ \sum z_n\text{ converges}  \Rightarrow \|z_n\| \to 0 $$